# Big Rudin exercise 1.10: Convergence of bounded function sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

**Exercise 1.10:** Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$, $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded complex measurable functions on $X$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X$. Prove that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X f_n d{\mu} = \int_X f d \mu $$
I saw an answer (I think it's right) which is organized as follows:

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon>0$ as given, and there is an $N$ such that $|f_n (x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/\mu(X)$ for all $n \geq N$ and $x \in X$. Then we have
$$ |\int_X f_n - f d \mu| \leq \int_X |f_n - f| d \mu < \epsilon $$
For any $\epsilon$, there is a corresponding $N$, which implies
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X (f_n - f) d \mu = 0 $$
It is equivalent to
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f_n d \mu = \int_X f d \mu $$

*Q.E.D*

My questions are:

1. Is the above proof correct?
2. If so, which step of the proof uses the condition that $\{f_n\}$ is bounded? Is this condition crucial?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is correct, but it should be observed that $f$ is also a bounded measurable function. Boundedness is needed for existence of $\int f_n d\mu$ and $\int f d\mu$. .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will the proof (or even the theorem) still hold if we replace the condition of boundedness with $f_n \in L^1 (\mu)$?

Comment: Yes, that is is also fine.